# Smart rounding by number of digits in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter, rounding

Hi I want to smart round a float number, to keep the number of digits constant.
This number will always have 1 or 2 integer digits + undefined decimal digits.

I want to have a number with always 3 digits regardless of their position

EX:

```
83.235 = 83.2
0.110321 = 0.11
4.56723 = 4.57
```

Comment: What if you have `4672.1145`?

Comment: Can't happen. The integer part is max 99 by specification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If leading zeroes don't count as digits**

NSNumberFormatter has [usesSignificantDigits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatter/1417793-usessignificantdigits), [minimumSignificantDigits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatter/1410174-minimumsignificantdigits?language=objc), and [maximumSignificantDigits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatter/1412008-maximumsignificantdigits?language=objc) properties that should do what you need.  Set both values to 3, or just the max if you don't want trailing zeroes on values with fewer decimal places.

**If you want leading zeroes to count as digits**

I'm not aware of any built-in way of handling this, but you could write some custom logic to do it.  e.g.

```
if (yourNum < 10)
    formattedNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", yourNum];
else
    formattedNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", yourNum];
```

This is assuming the number is always between 0 and 99.whatever, so if you're not 100% confident in the data integrity you'll probably want some more checks.

Comment: I'm trying to use this code     NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:1];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    [formatter setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];
    [formatter setMinimumSignificantDigits:2];
    [formatter setMaximumSignificantDigits:3];
    
But sometimes I still get 0.123 or 0.110

Comment: @lorenzop See my edit if you want the leading zero to count as a digit too.